# Bootstrap 4 cursor for custom-control in state disabled

Tags: css, bootstrap-4, twitter-bootstrap-4

I need other cursor for disabled custom-control elements (checkbox, radiobutton)

This style don't work:

```
.custom-control-input:disabled ~ .custom-control-label::before {
    cursor: not-allowed;
}
```

Comment: You should show the HTML that you're selecting. Make sure that it's actually selecting the right parts, and stuff like that

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For disabled custom-control elements in Bootstrap 4 (checkbox, radio button), you need the following selector css rule/selector:

```
.custom-control-input:disabled ~ .custom-control-label {
    cursor: not-allowed;
}
```

And if you wanted the custom cursor style only for the actual checkbox/radio button but not for the label (*not recommended* in this case), then you'd need this rule:

```
.custom-control-input:disabled ~ .custom-control-label::after {
    cursor: not-allowed;
}
```

Click "run code snippet" below to see it working:

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-Gn5384xqQ1aoWXA+058RXPxPg6fy4IWvTNh0E263XmFcJlSAwiGgFAW/dAiS6JXm" crossorigin="anonymous">
    
<style>
.custom-control-input:disabled~.custom-control-label {
    cursor: not-allowed;
}
</style>

<form class="m-3">
    <div class="custom-control custom-radio custom-control-inline">
        <input type="radio" id="customRadioInline1" name="customRadioInline1" class="custom-control-input">
        <label class="custom-control-label" for="customRadioInline1">This custom radio is OK</label>
    </div>
    <div class="custom-control custom-radio custom-control-inline">
        <input type="radio" id="customRadioInline2" name="customRadioInline1" class="custom-control-input" disabled>
        <label class="custom-control-label" for="customRadioInline2">This one is disabled</label>
    </div>
    
    <div class="custom-control custom-checkbox">
        <input type="checkbox" class="custom-control-input" id="customCheck1">
        <label class="custom-control-label" for="customCheck1">This custom checkbox is OK</label>
    </div>
    <div class="custom-control custom-checkbox">
        <input type="checkbox" class="custom-control-input" id="customCheck2">
        <label class="custom-control-label" for="customCheck2">OK too</label>
    </div>
    <div class="custom-control custom-checkbox">
        <input type="checkbox" class="custom-control-input" id="customCheckDisabled" disabled>
        <label class="custom-control-label" for="customCheckDisabled">This custom checkbox is disabled</label>
    </div>
    
</form>
```